# How correct is my model for User and Message?

Tags: database, prisma

I wrote a model for a user and a message, but for some reason it seems to me that I missed something, what is wrong in the model? How to improve it?

```
model User {
  id               Int       @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email            String    @unique
  username         String    @unique
  password         String
  createdAt        DateTime  @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt        DateTime  @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  sentMessages     Message[] @relation("Sender")
  receivedMessages Message[] @relation("Recipient")
}

model Message {
  id          Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  text        String
  senderId    Int
  sender      User     @relation("Sender", fields: [senderId], references: [id])
  recipientId Int
  recipient   User     @relation("Recipient", fields: [recipientId], references: [id])
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
}
```

Comment: I hope your passwords are stored as a strongly encrypted hash...

Comment: Yes, I hash passwords, that's fine

Comment: I planned to make not only private messages, but also chat rooms

Comment: For chat rooms, I suggest a Chat model.